# how to send wordpress site to someone

Tags: wordpress

I have a localhost xampp wordpress website/theme, I need to send it to someone via email zip file, and they have to open it with a html file. I am thinking of creating a html file that re directs them to the index.php file. But im not sure, do they have to install it on their own localserver? Its just to view the website once. They also have to login to the administration part of the wordpress site. Its hard to find this on google since most people ask about sending email newsletters and such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is no way to run a PHP CMS or script without a php interpreter and an http server.
you can use a free host to install wordpress...

Comment: thanks for answering, can you name a host server I can use for this? thank you

Comment: ok thank you, do you think this client doesn't understand this? why would they ask me to do it this way?

Comment: I think they want to be sure every thing works correctly. and if an answer is helpful just vote it up an tick it!

Comment: ok thank you. still not really understand but I will ask them why.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they would have to host it on their local server to view it.  Your local server is not connected to the Web so redirecting to it won't work.

Alternatively, you could host it somewhere but that might be outside the scope of what you are trying to do for a one time visit.

Comment: thanks for answering, is there a way I can send them a zip and once they open it on their computer they can login in to the admin part?

Comment: That might work but they would need xamp installed and you would have to send your wordpress files along with any relevant sql tables.